# WSO2 AS (5.3.0) - "Deployment Synchronizer" page Not found

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

I followed the official guide to set up a cluster (Clustering AS 5.3.0) (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+AS+5.3.0).

and also configured the SVN-based Deployment Synchronizer.

but i cannot found the "Deployment Synchronizer" page on mgt console (https://localhost:9443/carbon/deployment-sync/index.jsp.)

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <AutoCommit>true</AutoCommit>
        <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
        <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
        <SvnUrl>https://10.13.46.34:8443/svn/repos/as</SvnUrl>
        <SvnUser>svnuser</SvnUser>
        <SvnPassword>svnuser-password</SvnPassword>     
        <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>true</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
    </DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

So, anyone can tell me how to find the deployment-sync page? 
Similar page(WSO2 4.1.2 ): 
[image]

thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that page? There aren't any such page. From where do you get the reference to that page?

Comment: cause i wanna set the synchronization period manually , and enable/disable depSync on this page.    
Similar page(WSO2 4.1.2 ):   http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-92R83muEJjI/T6kJYz4ipyI/AAAAAAAAFNI/5fsHJohyjK8/s1600/DepSync-UI-wso2-appserver.png

Answer (score 1):

That page is not longer exist in any of the WSO2 products.

When you have a cluster of WSO2 products, the master node will notify the worker nodes through a cluster message when there is a change in artifacts, so that, worker nodes will synch up the changes through SVN based deployment synchronizer.

You can achieve it through [cronjob](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/). You don't really need to have SVN-Based Deployment Synchronizer.